# Getting xml from wikipedia page

Tags: xml, parsing, wikipedia

I'm trying to parse wikipedia pages from xml.
I'm using Special:Export link to get the xml of the page with links like that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Bruce_Willis

But when I'm trying to get a File or Category page I can't use this link, for example, this pages don't returning xml:

http:// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Category:English-language_films

http:// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/File:Bruce_Willis_by_Gage_Skidmore.jpg

I found a solution but I don't understand it:

1. Prefix the namespace to the page names (e.g. 'Help:Contents'),
   unless the selected namespace is the main namespace.
2. Repeat the steps above for other namespaces (e.g. Category:,
   Template:, etc.)

This solution I found at http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Export.
What is this means please.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you are refering to. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Category:English-language_films does generate an XML for me. Were you looking for the _list of pages_ in a category instead?

Comment: yes, that what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

`Special:Export` generates the content of a given page, but 'list of articles of a category' or a 'file' are not pages. What you get from Export will only be the xml of the category or file description page.

To retrive a list of pages beloning to a certain category, you need the MediaWiki API: `Categorymembers.`

Try [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:English-language_films). You may also play around with the [API Sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=categorymembers&format=xml) to understand different parameters.

You cannot download files directly. However, `imageinfo` API can generate the URL to a file for you, such as [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=imageinfo&format=xml&iiprop=url&titles=File%3ABruce_Willis_by_Gage_Skidmore.jpg).

See also: [Download images with MediaWiki API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500021/download-images-with-mediawiki-api)